# Proving a consequence of the Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The following statement is said to be an immediate consequence of the Intermediate Value Theorem:

Let $I,J \subset \mathbb{R}$ be closed intervals satisfying $I \subset J$ and $J \subset f(I)$. Then $f$ possesses a fixed point in $I$.

My approach:

Let $ J = [a,b]$. Since $J \subset f(I)$ there exist $c,d \in I$ such that $f(c) = a$ and $f(d) = b$.

At this point I do not really know how to continue although I think that I have proven a special case, which is the following:

Suppose that $I = [c,d]$. Define $h(x) = f(x) - x$. Since $I \subset J$ we have $h(c) = f(c) - c = a - c < 0$ and $h(d) = f(d) - d = b - d > 0$. Now the Intermediate Value Theorem can be applied and states that there is $\xi \in [c,d] = I$ such that $h(\xi) = 0$. That is $f(\xi) = \xi$ and therefore we would be finished.

In general it is not clear that $I = [c,d]$, is it?

Can anyone give a hint or help out proving the above statement?

Comment: You have basically done it yourself already. Just note that $[c,d]\subset I\subset J$, by your own result $f$ has a fixed point in $[c,d]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is alsmost complete. All you really need to check is what happens if $a=c$ or $b=d$ You didn't use the fact that $I=[c,d]$ anywhere in your proof. All you really used was the fact that $[c,d]\subseteq I$, which is true.

In particular:

- $h(c)=f(c)-c = a-c$ is true from the definitions of $h$ and $c$.
- $a-c<0$... well, almost. You actually have $a-c\leq 0$, but that's ok. I mean, it it's equal to $0$, then you're fine already, since $f(c)-c=0$ and $c$ is a fixed point.
- $h(d)=f(d)-d=b-d$ again, true from the definitions.
- $b-d>0$... same as above.
- Then, we apply the intermediate value theorem.
- Then, $h(\xi)=0$, and $\xi\in[c,d]$.

There is no point at which you used the fact that $I=[c,d]$.

Comment: If $a=c$ or $b=d$ then $a$ or $b$ are fixed points and we would be finished. I should have thought about it for a bit longer but at least I'm confident now that the proof is (more or less) complete and correct. Thank you!

Comment: @offline Yes, the cases $a=c$ and $b=d$ are simple, but you do still need to mention them for the proof to be complete. Well done on the proof.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thank you!